# Python Selenium: Determine X-path of elements located by class name?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, automation

I have the following code:

```
x = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'formpic'))
```

This locates several elements with the classname `formpic`. Is there a way to calculate the X-path of each of the elements in a for loop? I'm needing to grab an element and content related to it based on X-path. As an example:

```
Image I need: /html/body/div[2]/div[2]/main/div[2]/table[8]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/img

Info related to image: /html/body/div[2]/div[2]/main/div[2]/table[8]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]
```

By incrementing the last `tr` I can easily extract info related to the image because the document follows this pattern. The problem is, the x-path of each image is variable because the content on each page is variable.

Comment: Can you share a link to that page?

Comment: https://www.serebii.net/pokedex-swsh/alcremie/. So I want to grab the image of the pokemon and the description with it. For example: This image `https://www.serebii.net/swordshield/pokemon/869.png` and this description `Spin clockwise quickly in the day.
Strawberry Sweet
Hold Strawberry Sweet`

Comment: I'm trying to scrape data from Serebii to create my own dex and sort the dex by locations in the game eventually.

Answer (score 0):

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,60)                                 
driver.get('https://www.serebii.net/pokedex-swsh/alcremie/')
pics=wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//table[8]//table//tr[./td[@class='pkmn']]")))
print(len(pics))
for i in range(0,int(len(pics)/3),3):
    
    name=pics[i].find_element(By.XPATH,".//td/b").text
    desc=pics[i+2].find_element(By.XPATH,".//td").text
    hold=pics[i+2].find_element(By.XPATH,".//td/a/br").text
    print(name,desc,hold)
```

You'd do it something like this with a loop. You can add a split and however you want to fix the br and element as a text node.

Import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```